# SQL distinct or group by

Tags: sql, group-by, distinct

My brain aint functioning atm.. Can you pls help me out here:

Got a table with `date, analyseid, groupid`

I want to get unique groupid's.. perhaps with a count on same groupid's. Also if there are rows with same groupid the date is also the same.

```
SELECT     date, analyseid,  COUNT(*) AS 'amount', groupid
FROM         myTable
GROUP BY groupid
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `GROUP BY` all columns you want to `SELECT` (except of aggregate functions):

```
SELECT     date, analyseid,  COUNT(*) AS 'amount', groupid
FROM         myTable
GROUP BY date, analyseid,  groupid
ORDER BY date DESC
```

If you want only `groupid` and the respective counts, then remove `date, analyseid` both from `SELECT` and from `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS 'amount', groupid
FROM         myTable
GROUP BY groupid
```

Comment: you have to `GROUP BY` all the columns you want to select **except for aggregate columns**